# DioError (DioError [DioErrorType.other]: Converting object to an encodable object failed: LinkedHashSet len:1

Tags: flutter, dio

This is my body. I'm getting this error. DioError (DioError [DioErrorType.other]: Converting object to an encodable object failed: LinkedHashSet len:1

```
var params ={[{
    "Name": "String",
    "Address": "String",
    "Details": "Sample",
    "Notes": "Sample",
    "Coordinates": {
      "Latitude": latitude,
      "Longitude": longitude
    },
    "IsPrimary": false
    }]};
```

Comment: can i add the code where you use dio ?

Comment: var dio = d.Dio();
    d.Response address;
    dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = _sessionService.information!.authKey;
    dio.options.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"; here is my DIO

Comment: [Edit] instead of commenting please.